# Newrelic: How do I know which php-script is making a lot of database queries?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, optimization, newrelic

I have installed New Relic in my server to optimize an existing CodeIgniter project. 
There are some controllers and models which are running database queries inside loop.
I have fixed most of such cases which I could found, but I want to know if there are still some script which are running queries inside a loop.

How do I find such scripts in New Relic or in general ?

Comment: I dont know much of newrelic but try CIs native benchmark, profiler tools.

Comment: Thanks for responding @Kyslik but I have to check it in production. I can not turn on profiler there :(

Comment: well make a copy and run it on localhost, is that out of question too?

Comment: Well, it will take too much time, I have purchased newrelic subscription for a reason, I want to monitor these things in realtime.

Answer (score 3):

You can check out your database report in New Relic to see which queries have the highest throughput, and investigate if this is expected or not. You can also filter queries by "Slowest queries by controller" so this will show SQL data (and what controller invoked this) on a controller & query basis. This may be a good place to start to focus on performance issues that need attention.

You can also enable your database log to see all SQL queries that are being executed. This is most likely not helpful in a production environment, as you will have many queries adding too much noise to the log for proper investigation.

You should also check out what the MySQL plugin can add regarding visibility into MySQL performance (this is a free plugin that all New Relic customers can use):
http://newrelic.com/plugins/new-relic-inc/52

Potentially most useful of all, you should definitely look at some transaction traces for the scripts you wish to optimize, and see what DB activity looks like as far as multiple queries happening in succession. If you want to make a particular transaction more likely to be traced, you can make it a "Key Transaction". Once you start getting traces, you can see what happens in the execution of this script in a easy to view "tree". SQL data will also be recorded, so you can see exactly what was being performed during this transaction.